# MAUI: Push notification for iOS platform

Tags: maui

I am using `Plugin.Firebase` and `Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics` packages for implementing push notification in my MAUI application. I referred [this](https://www.andreasnesheim.no/push-notifications-in-net-maui-with-firebase/) blog and it was working fine on the Android platform. Now I am implementing it for the iOS platform.

I have done below set up on iOS platform:

1. I have added Push Notification service into the app’s identifier on apple developer website.
2. Created a new provisioning profile, install it on the device and bind it to the project settings.
3. Created a new key.(.P8 file) and uploaded it into the FCM console. When uploading the key, provided the Team Id and Key Id.

**Pending Set UP**

1. I need to enable the `Remote Notification` on Info.plist file. It was under `Capabilities` tab on Xamarin Forms application. But on MAUI there is no such tab.

[image]

2. I need to enable the Push Notifications in the `Entitlements.plist`, but that file is not found on the MAUI iOS folder. Should I need to create it and How can I create such type of files?

**After all these 2 pending set up, is FCM token will generate or anything else is pending to do on iOS platform?**

Below is my FCM token function and it was working fine for Android platform:

```
private async void GetToken()
{
    await CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.CheckIfValidAsync();
    var token = await CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.GetTokenAsync();
    Preferences.Default.Set("devicefcmtoken", token);
    Console.WriteLine($"FCM token::>> {token}");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to enable the Remote Notification on `Info.plist` file. It was
> under Capabilities tab on Xamarin Forms application. But on MAUI there
> is no such tab.

You can manually edit the `Info.plist` by adding the following key/value pair to enable the Remote Notification:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
```

> I need to enable the Push Notifications in the Entitlements.plist, but
> that file is not found on the MAUI iOS folder. Should I need to create
> it and How can I create such type of files?

To [add a new entitlements file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/entitlements?tabs=vs#add-an-entitlementsplist-file) to your .NET MAUI app project, add a new XML file named `Entitlements.plist` to the Platforms\iOS folder of your app project. Then add the following XML to the file. And then add [Push notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/entitlements?tabs=vs#push-notifications) to the `Entitlements.plist`. The entitlement is defined using the aps-environment key, of type String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

For more information, see [APS Environment Entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/aps-environment?language=objc) on developer.apple.com.